# How to incorporate many features into a TensorFlow Probability Structural Time Series

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, linear-regression, tensorflow-probability

I'm wondering how to train a Multivariate Bayesian Structural Time Series (BSTS) model that automatically performs feature selection on hundreds of input time series using Tensorflow Probability.

The [TF-Probability BSTS blog post](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/structural-time-series-modeling-in.html) shows how to include seasonal effects alongside a single input feature:

```
  ...
  temp_effect = sts.LinearRegression(
      design_matrix=tf.reshape(temp - np.mean(temp),
                               (-1, 1)), name='temp_effect')
  ...
  model = sts.Sum([..., temp_effect,...],
                   observed_time_series=observed_time_series)
```

But what about when there are multiple input time series?

Reading through the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.9.0/tensorflow_probability/python/sts/regression.py) makes it seem that with many inputs the SparseLinearRegression would be preferrable, which makes sense, but how should I adapt my code?

The documentation for both LinearRegression and SparseLinearRegression method suggests using `design_matrix=tf.stack([series1, series2], axis=-1), weights_prior_scale=0.1)`, but since that's different from how TF-Probability's own blog post uses it I am unsure if that is the best way to go.

Should I be adding all (several hundred) input features inside the `design_matrix` of a single SparseLinearRegression, or should I be adding a separate LinearRegression for each feature and then use `sts.Sum()` to combine them all into the model? Though I would like the functionality of visualizing the impact of each feature, I am most interested in having the model automatically perform feature selection and generate weights for the remaining features which I can have access to.